# The mechanism for the addition of HCl to propylene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

**Problem:**

The mechanism for the addition of HCl to propylene is described below.

[image]

Complete the mechanism in step 1 with *one* curved arrow showing the electron movement that occurs when the double bond is broken, as well as the mechanism in step 2 with the intermediate carbocation and *one* curved arrow showing how $Cl^-$ is added.

**Solution:**

No solution was given to this problem.

**What I am thinking:**

Excuse how messily I've drawn everything. I just drew this fast on a notepad I specifically have to just aid me in trying to find the right solution before I write and draw everything more nicely on another notepad.

[image]

**Questions:**

Did I draw the curved arrows where they are supposed to be? Did I write the right carbocation? Am I thinking right?

Comment: Basically correct